# Using Celery for long running async jobs

Tags: python, asynchronous, celery

I'm having different python programs doing long polling at different machines, and am thinking of a queuing based mechanism to manage the load and provide an async job functionality.

These programs are standalone, and aren't part of any framework.

I'm primarily thinking about Celery due to its ability for multi-processing and sharing tasks across multiple celery workers. Is celery a good choice here, or am I better off simply using an event based system with RabbitMQ directly?

Comment: Or maybe directly with the new async functionality later python3+

Comment: @svrist I'm already using asyncio for the polling at present. I wanted to parallelize this and also provide a queueing system for distributing the tasks. Isn't celery a good fit here?

Comment: Celery is a good candidate to solve these kinds of problems. Go with Rabbit directly can be very painful, I suggest using it only for specific performance problems. Another "easy to use" solution can Redis Rq: https://python-rq.org/

Comment: Or Huey 2 - https://huey.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ - if Celery seems complicated. Personally, I think Celery is the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say yes - Celery is definitely a good choice! We do have tasks that run sometimes for over 20 hours, and Celery works just fine. Furthermore it is extremely simple to setup and use (Celery + Redis is supersimple).

Comment: Is it really that simple to use? I've seen rants from a lot of people get into wierd errors with Celery. While I'm sticking to celery right now for the test phase, I'll consider the other alternatives given on the comments as well if things go south.

Comment: People, including me, gave you alternatives in our comments.